# Django ManyToMany field is not created in model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my Model for Teacher class.

```
class Teacher(Profile):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'teacher'

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='teacher')

    home_address =  models.CharField(_('home_address'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    home_phone =  models.CharField(_('home_phone'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    cell_phone =  models.CharField(_('cell_phone'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    experience =  models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    summary =  models.TextField(_('summary'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subjects, through='SubjectsIntermediate')
```

When i execute the `manage.py syncdb` it does creates the `teacher` table with all fields except for field `subjects`. Why the `subjects` field is not created??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because a ManyToMany isn't a field, at least not one that exists as a database column. It's a relationship with a linking table. You'll find that a table named `myapp_teacher_subjects` has been created, with foreign keys to both teacher and subjects.

Comment: Just not `myapp_teacher_subjects` table, but `myapp_subjectsintermediate`, because of `through` arg.