# Django. Invalid keyword argument for this function. ManyToMany

Tags: django

I have this error:

**'people' is an invalid keyword argument for this function**

```
class Passage(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    who = models.ForeignKey(UserProfil)

class UserPassage(models.Model):
    passage = models.ForeignKey(Passage)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfil, null=True)

class UserProfil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I try:

```
def join(request):
    user = request.user
    user_profil = UserProfil.objects.get(user=user)
    passage = Passage.objects.get(id=2)
    #line with error
    up = UserPassage.objects.create(people= user_profil, passage=passage)
    return render_to_response('thanks.html')
```

How does one do this correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to save/create the object before you can add `ManyToMany` relationships:

```
up = UserPassage.objects.create(passage=passage)
up.people.add(user_profil)
```

`ManyToMany` relationships aren't saved as columns in your table. Read the first reply here for good explanation:

[Django ManyToMany field is not created in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080177/django-manytomany-field-is-not-created-in-model)

> @DanielRoseman: Because a ManyToMany isn't a field, at least not one that exists as a database column. It's a relationship with a linking table. You'll find that a table named myapp_teacher_subjects has been created, with foreign keys to both teacher and subjects.