# Django: "'p' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" in ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, forms, model-view-controller, web

I'm getting a failure when trying to access data from a record out of a field that corresponds to a `ManyToManyField`.

**models.py**

```
class I(models.Model):
   t = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   p = models.ManyToManyField(P)

class P(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
   t = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput())
   p = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=P.objects.all().order_by('name'),
                              widget=forms.SelectMultiple())
   # other_fields_requiring_custom_save = ...

def save(self):
    I = I.objects.create(
        t = self.data['t'],
        p = self.data['p'], 
    )
    I.save() # it breaks here: 'P' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" in ManyToManyField
```

It breaks on `save` when I try to set `p = self.data['p']`.  In the debugger I can see:

```
data = <QueryDict: {u'p': [u'2', u'1'], u't': [u'aaa'], ... >
```

Comment: The argument to `ManyToManyField` has to be another model.  From what you've shown, you don't have `class P(models.Model)` defined anywhere in your `models.py`.

Comment: Can you us traceback of the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a many-to-many association in `create` by passing it to the keyword argument `p`.  You need to set the association separately, not in the create.  You can also look into how to optimize the queries so the create and the setting-many-to-many don't turn into too many queries.  See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144051/django-invalid-keyword-argument-for-this-function-manytomany).